# Disaster management Class shows "cannot be applied" to User u2 error

Tags: java

I'm working on this lab where I'm creating a hypothetical disaster management system for people to put information about disasters with Java. Within the code, there are two classes with the same name `User`. The tutorial for the lab says that line 75 with `user u2` is supposed to use an Emergency Contact class by using the following code:

```java
  User u2 = new User("Marlena", "Evans","6088861222", "me@daysofourlives.com");
```

However, with this, the console brings up this error:
`'User(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' in 'User' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, boolean, int, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)'`

so I changed it to:

```java
 User u2 = new User("Marlena", "Evans", false, 30, "6088861222","me@daysofourlives.com");
```

which removed the error.

I need a fresh set of eyes on this. Can someone look at this and tell me why the tutorial's code isn't working?

Here is what the code is supposed to look like:

[image]

and here is my code:

```java
//import java.sql.Timestamp (package already active)

public class User {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private boolean gender; //true - male; false - female
    private int age;
    private BloodType blood;
    private String telephone;
    private String email;
    private User emergencyContact;
    public  void setContact(User u){
        this.emergencyContact = u;
    }

    public User (
            String firstName,
            String lastName,
            boolean gender,
            int age,
            String blood,
            String telephone,
            String email
    ) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.age = age;
        this.blood = BloodType.fromString(blood);
        this.telephone = telephone;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getFirstName(){
        return this.firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName(){
        return this.lastName;
    }

    public boolean getGender(){
        return this.gender;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }

    public String getTelephone(){
        return this.telephone;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public BloodType getBlood() {
        return this.blood;
    }

    public User getEmergencyContact() {
        return this.emergencyContact;
    }
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO

         //Here is an example of using the new user constructor
        User u1 = new User("John","Black",true,25, "6085551234","jb@daysof" +
                "ourlives.com");
        //This example uses the Emergency Contact Constructor to create a new emergency contact
        User u2 = new User("Marlena", "Evans", false, 30, "6088861222","me@daysofourlives.com");

        u1.setContact(u2); //This means Marlena is the Emergency Contact for John

        System.out.println("User: " + u1.firstName + " has an emergency contact of: " + u1.emergencyContact.getFirstName());
    }

    public User (
            String firstName,
            String lastName,
            boolean gender,
            int age,
            String telephone,
            String email
    ){
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.age = age;
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

Thank you and as always, let me know if you need more context to help me.

Comment: In your code you have a single `User` class with two overloaded constructors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an additional constructor with the reduced number of arguments that constructor call in line 75 is using.

Add this to your User class:

```
  public User(String firstName, String lastName, String telephone, String email) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.telephone = telephone;
        this.email = email;
    }
```

Also, in the main class, you are accessing firstName and emergencyContact fields, but these are private fields, so either set them to public or add a setter method.

Comment: Could you tell me which line to add it?

Comment: The line does not really matter, just add it inside the class, so one option would be to add it just before the last "}". is this OK?